# how to permanently checked checkbox android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have following code:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@key/pref_airship"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_airship" />
```

According to this code, Checkbox is checked when application started first time. But i want that checkbox is permanently checked and user can't uncheck this checkbox(for example it changes it color and remain always checked). Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: disable clicks in the java code (not XML).  Do the following somewhere in your onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), or where ever you set up your preference layout:

```
CheckBoxPreference airshipPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_airship");
airshipPref.setEnabled(false);
```

That way, it will not handle clicks and it should not listen to user input, thereby remaining always checked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can inherit `CheckBoxPreference` to create custom preference:

```
public class DisabledCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference{

        public DisabledCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public DisabledCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public DisabledCheckBoxPreference(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindView(View view) {
            view.setEnabled(false);
            super.onBindView(view);
        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
<com.your.package.name.DisabledCheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@key/pref_airship"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_airship" />
```